# ERROR: u-boot-1_2020.01-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm new to yocto project and I was trying to build an image for lichee pi board. during the build process i got these errors:

```
ERROR: u-boot-1_2020.01-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: u-boot-1_2020.01-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/temp/run.do_compile.6782' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/temp/log.do_compile.6782
```

and this is the log file :

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
NOTE: make -j 3 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  --sysroot=/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot V=1 HOSTCC=gcc  -isystem/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 STAGING_INCDIR=/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include STAGING_LIBDIR=/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib -C /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git O=/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/build all
make: Entering directory '/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git'
make -C /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/build KBUILD_SRC=/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git \
-f /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/Makefile all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/build'
set -e; : '  CHK     include/config/uboot.release'; mkdir -p include/config/;   echo "2020.01$(/bin/bash /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/setlocalversion /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git)" < include/config/auto.conf > include/config/uboot.release.tmp; if [ -r include/config/uboot.release ] && cmp -s include/config/uboot.release include/config/uboot.release.tmp; then rm -f include/config/uboot.release.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/config/uboot.release'; mv -f include/config/uboot.release.tmp include/config/uboot.release; fi
ln -fsn /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git source
set -e; : '  CHK     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h'; mkdir -p include/generated/;     (if test -n "${SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH}"; then SOURCE_DATE="@${SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH}"; DATE=""; for date in gdate date.gnu date; do ${date} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" >/dev/null 2>&1 && DATE="${date}"; done; if test -n "${DATE}"; then LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_DATE "%b %d %C%y"'; LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_TIME "%T"'; LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_TZ "%z"'; LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_DMI_DATE "%m/%d/%Y"'; LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_BUILD_DATE 0x%Y%m%d'; else return 42; fi; else LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_DATE "%b %d %C%y"'; LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_TIME "%T"'; LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_TZ "%z"'; LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_DMI_DATE "%m/%d/%Y"'; LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_BUILD_DATE 0x%Y%m%d'; fi) < /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/Makefile > include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h'; mv -f include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h.tmp include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h; fi
/bin/bash /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/mkmakefile \
    /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git . 2020 01
make -f /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
  GEN     ./Makefile
rm -f .tmp_quiet_recordmcount
make -f /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts
if [ -f /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/.config -o -d /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/include/config ]; then \
    echo >&2 "  /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git is not clean, please run 'make mrproper'"; \
    echo >&2 "  in the '/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git' directory.";\
    /bin/false; \
fi;
make -f /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/dtc
set -e; : '  CHK     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h'; mkdir -p include/generated/;   (echo \#define PLAIN_VERSION \"2020.01""-g303f8fe\"; echo \#define U_BOOT_VERSION \"U-Boot \" PLAIN_VERSION; echo \#define CC_VERSION_STRING \"$(LC_ALL=C arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  --sysroot=/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot --version | head -n 1)\"; echo \#define LD_VERSION_STRING \"$(LC_ALL=C arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld.bfd --version | head -n 1)\"; ) < include/config/uboot.release > include/generated/version_autogenerated.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/version_autogenerated.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/version_autogenerated.h include/generated/version_autogenerated.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/version_autogenerated.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h'; mv -f include/generated/version_autogenerated.h.tmp include/generated/version_autogenerated.h; fi
make -f /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/dtc/pylibfdt
  gcc  -isystem/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  -o scripts/dtc/dtc scripts/dtc/dtc.o scripts/dtc/flattree.o scripts/dtc/fstree.o scripts/dtc/data.o scripts/dtc/livetree.o scripts/dtc/treesource.o scripts/dtc/srcpos.o scripts/dtc/checks.o scripts/dtc/util.o scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o  
make -f /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/Makefile.build obj=.
  unset CROSS_COMPILE; unset CFLAGS; CC="gcc  -isystem/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" LDSHARED="gcc  -isystem/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -shared " LDFLAGS="" VERSION="u-boot-2020.01" CPPFLAGS="-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer  -std=gnu11 -I/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt" OBJDIR=scripts/dtc/pylibfdt SOURCES="/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt/fdt.c /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt/fdt_ro.c /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt/fdt_wip.c /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt/fdt_sw.c /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt/fdt_rw.c /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt/fdt_strerror.c /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt/fdt_empty_tree.c /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt/fdt_addresses.c /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt/fdt_overlay.c scripts/dtc/pylibfdt/libfdt.i" SWIG_OPTS="-I/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt -I/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/libfdt/.." python3 /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/dtc/pylibfdt/setup.py --quiet build_ext --inplace
mkdir -p lib/
mkdir -p arch/arm/lib/
set -e; : '  CHK     include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h'; mkdir -p include/generated/;     (set -e; echo "#ifndef __GENERIC_ASM_OFFSETS_H__"; echo "#define __GENERIC_ASM_OFFSETS_H__"; echo "/*"; echo " * DO NOT MODIFY."; echo " *"; echo " * This file was generated by Kbuild"; echo " */"; echo ""; sed -ne  "s:[[:space:]]*\.ascii[[:space:]]*\"\(.*\)\":\1:; /^->/{s:->#\(.*\):/* \1 */:; s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$#]*\([-0-9]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$#]*\([^ ]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; s:->::; p;}"; echo ""; echo "#endif" ) < lib/asm-offsets.s > include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h'; mv -f include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h.tmp include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h; fi
set -e; : '  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h'; mkdir -p include/generated/;     (set -e; echo "#ifndef __ASM_OFFSETS_H__"; echo "#define __ASM_OFFSETS_H__"; echo "/*"; echo " * DO NOT MODIFY."; echo " *"; echo " * This file was generated by Kbuild"; echo " */"; echo ""; sed -ne  "s:[[:space:]]*\.ascii[[:space:]]*\"\(.*\)\":\1:; /^->/{s:->#\(.*\):/* \1 */:; s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$#]*\([-0-9]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$#]*\([^ ]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; s:->::; p;}"; echo ""; echo "#endif" ) < arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s > include/generated/asm-offsets.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/asm-offsets.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/asm-offsets.h include/generated/asm-offsets.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/asm-offsets.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/asm-offsets.h'; mv -f include/generated/asm-offsets.h.tmp include/generated/asm-offsets.h; fi
/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/hosttools/ld: scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `yylloc'; scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:106: scripts/dtc/dtc] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/scripts/Makefile.build:432: scripts/dtc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git/Makefile:551: scripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/build'
make: *** [Makefile:167: sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/git'
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Execution of '/home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/work/licheepizero_dock-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2020.01-r0/temp/run.do_compile.6782' failed with exit code 1
```

I tryed to rebuild but it didn't work.
An answer to similar problem was that python is missing in the system but im pretty sure i have python on my system.

any help would be appreciate. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure where the exact correct location is for you to fix the code but an actual fix is seen here in a 2020 kernel patch
https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/4/1/1206

the actual error is shown by bitbake is here

> /home/apm/yocto/build/tmp/hosttools/ld:
> scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of
> `yylloc'; scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status